# I cant sync my project due to below error

Tags: javascript, android-studio, gradle, sdk

Could not resolve all files for configuration `':app:androidApis'`.

Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes `{artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, returnDefaultValues=false}. Execution failed for MockableJarTransform: C:\Users\vichu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar. Cannot parse result path string:` 
I tried cleaning and rebuilding project.

here is gradle and gradle wrapper versions :

**gradle** : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured the problem

Changed

**gradle** : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

To

**gradle** : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'